# AMCL does not localize my robot

Tags: amcl, nav2

I am trying to use AMCL (`nav2_amcl`) with my custom robot, but localization doesn't seem to run.

I launch my robot frames and a transform from `odom` to `base_footprint` frame, such that corresponding tf tree is shown below:

[image]

Additionally, I launch `rplidar` node, publish my map and run localization. My params are as follow:

```
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 30
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "differential"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.0
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    controller_frequency: 10.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.22
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.22
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 0
      vtheta_samples: 40
      sim_time: 1.5
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.05
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0
      
controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.3
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        inflation_radius: 1.0
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          obstacle_min_range: 0.3
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      robot_radius: 0.3
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          obstacle_min_range: 0.3
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    yaml_filename: "map.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: False
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: False
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 2000
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"   
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200
```

`update_min_d` is defined as 0.0 to perform a filter update without moving my robot.

When `initialPose` is requested, I set it through `rviz` and then local and global costmaps are shown, the robot is placed in the `initialPose` pose defined, but it does not localize.

[image]

I checked the tf tree, and a transform from `map` to `odom` is included, but it does not change (I guess it should change in order to localize my robot).

Am I missing anything else to get it working?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't localize? If it did "localize" in the way you expect, what woudl it do that it isn't doing?  The picture above looks prefectly reasonable to me. It looks just like it would on my system if I chose an inaccurate initial pose estimate. Are you expecting the robot to start moving to correct a bad pose estimate?

Comment: Hi,
I mean whenever I set the initial pose, the robot is placed there and nothing else happens. I think it should start trying to match the laser scan with the map since `update_min_d=0.0`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a few days coming because I wanted to test on HW and that robot needed repair.

Set the parameter to -0.01 and on my system it works.

```
ros2 param set /amcl update_min_d -0.01
```

I started the NAV2 stack with parameter set to 0.25, then used parameter server to set it to 0.0 and the first attempt I saw some very small changes to angles but no translation. The next time I tried 0.0 it did absolutely nothing. When setting to -0.01 it moved and rotated into position. I guess the code uses "> update_min_d" to decide to run a cycle or not.

CPU usage increased about 10%. Suggest try this for a few seconds after setting intial pose and then set it back to normal.